# Need some explaining

Tags: android, try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception

So this is the weirdest thing ever to happen to me during programing. Yes I'm no pro at programing, but I'm learning as I go. I've got an app talking to a server, a socket in the main thread, reading is done in a separate class and thread and writing in a separate class with asynctask.

The problem is LocationManager. I could talk to server and write/read commands just fine, I implemented the LocationManager and its listener.

I then proceeded to implement a method to update my textview with the new coordinates on locatinChanged. So far so good. Thing is when I use the Emulator control in eclipse and send coordinates the app crashed with a stringOutOfBoundsException (I've programed for 3 years now never seen this). I looked at the code stepped through it and so on. Read the stacktrace, logcat, console and everywhere I could think of but it got me nowhere. Until I finally went to the readerthread which looks like this:

```
    public class ReaderThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){                  
                try {
                    //Establish a bufferedreader to read from the socket/server.
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()), 8 * 1024);
            } 
            catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        
        //As long as connect is true.       
        while (connected) {
            String line;
            try {
                //Try to read a line from the reader.
                line = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
                if (in == null) {
                    //No one has sent a message yet.
                    System.out.println("No data recieved");
                }
            
                else {
                    int i = 0;
                    //As long as someone is sending messages.
                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null ){
                         //Make a new Message.
                        Message msg;
                        msg = new Message();
                        //Set the object to the input line.
                        msg.obj = line;
                        //Set an id so it can be identified in the main class and used in a switch.
                        msg.what = i;
                        System.out.println("i is: "+i);
                        //Send the message to the handler.
                        Main.this.h.sendMessage(msg);   
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        
            }           
        }).start(); 
    }
```

The variable i is in an if statement depending on what the server sent but I cut that out as it has nothing to do with this problem.

The problem is the freaking catch. When the catch is IOException, the app crashes. Out of dumb luck I changed this to Exception and printed  e.message to catch the error and see what caused it. Thing is this change fixed it. How can switching IOException to just plain Exception fix a problem like this?

Its like with IOException the program says: "hey your not gonna catch the error but there is no error" but with Exception it says "Well now you could catch it so I'll proceed".

My app is working but I just can't grasp this, why and how does this happen?

Comment: You keep saying the code is working, but that is demonstrably false, or you wouldn't be here. @twaddington has told you what the problem is - if you only catch an IOException, then your app will crash when it comes across any other exception. Instead, catching Exception will catch every possible exception. That's why your app no longer crashes, not because there's anything strange going on, but because you're ignoring every possible run-time error and so it will silently continue but will be in an indeterminate state.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the question. I am here because the code is working but it shouldnt. I have my desired functionality. Everything is doing what it should, ive tested this again and again. I know what the server should respond because I have the server side by side with my client on another computer with a textfile of its functionality. I send a command and I get the correct response. I set my coordinates and I get the correct respone which I intercept with and if and a substring on the response which works. But logically (for me) it shouldnt work.

Comment: Well, how about this - by catching all exceptions, you allow the thread to be started, but you are not correctly handling the error state that causes the exception to be thrown - you are, in effect just ignoring it. Since the thread is allowed to start, it will give the impression that just by catching all exceptions, you have fixed the bug when in fact you have just ignored it. As I said in my original comment - you are just ignoring the problem, not fixing it.

Comment: I recommend you re-read everybody's comments, read a good book/tutorial on Java exception handling, and you will see why you are just setting yourself up for even more confusing bugs further down the road.

Comment: @RivieraKid: but the surprising thing is apparently the program's _side effects_ are happening as expected -- which is definitely strange, since I certainly wouldn't expect this code to work. I'm baffled why this code appears to function properly -- and if I were responsible for maintaining it, I'd _definitely_ re-write the whole thing so it works as I expect.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially telling the application to catch the base `Exception` class. This means that any type of error will be caught, since all exception classes descend from that base type. Since `StringOutOfBoundsException` does not descend from `IOException` it was not being caught before and the error was not being caught. Instead of catching all exceptions, you might try the following:

```
try {
    // Your code here...
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Caught an IOException!", e);
} catch (StringOutOfBoundsException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Caught a string out of bounds Exception!", e);
}
```

I'm unable to determine what is actually throwing the `StringOutOfBoundsException` to begin with. It may be in the if statement that you cut out of your example.

Comment: Yes im aware of that. The thing is I only changed IOException to Exception NOTHING else. So what caused the error if there even was one? Changing a catch shouldn fix an error? Just catching an error that existed right? What causes the error was implementing a locationlistener that sent my coordinates to the server so when i used the emulator controls to set coordinates it crashed while reading the response

Comment: Appending: No the if only caught the incoming message and set i to depending on what the message was, if it wasnt something I wanted to catch it just printed to system.out.println. THe if was added after I fixed the error aswell so the if has nothing to do with it

Comment: Read it again and yes IOException doesnt catch outofbound on the string but changing the catch "fixes" a problem that obviously never existed. By changing the catch and only the catch the app works just fine so there was never an error to catch. It feels like eclipse is telling me that I couldnt ever catch that error therefor im crashing your app, fix the catch and ill allow you to continue.

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (connected) {
        String line;
        try {
            //Try to read a line from the reader.
            line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
            if (in == null) {
                //No one has sent a message yet.
                System.out.println("No data recieved");
            }
```

The test for `in == null` is in a funny location. You should receive a `NullPointerException` if that test were to ever return `true` by nature of calling methods on it a few lines earlier. Obviously something is a little funny with this code.

You fail to save the return value from `in.readLine()` the second time you call it. I hope it did not contain anything useful. (Though, since you print the line, you obviously wanted to know what data it contained.)

Whatever that `line` *was* (from the first call to `in.readLine()`), it gets thrown away; there's nothing else in the loop that uses it before it is over-written on this line:

```
                while((line = in.readLine()) != null ){
```

At this point, the two lines that you read are gone forever.

I'm not entirely sure what should be done to fix this; if it were me, I'd be sorely tempted to start over with a sheet of paper and sketch out what the method should be doing without looking at the existing code, then compare the sketch against the code to see which cases each one has overlooked.

Comment: Yes this code is a total spaghetti mess I know that, Ive just scrapped together crap to work and it does. Nothing needs to be fixed, this code works. The thing is that changin the catch from IOException to plain Exception fixed it somehow. Why?

Comment: I could post my entire class and subclasses but to be honest the code looks like crap but it works and im not that good with android so I get by with using "less then optimal" options as im used to C# and ive isolated the problem to the read thread and posting all of my code would embarras me :p.

Comment: I just noticed on a re-read that you're calling `in.readLine()` _twice_ in that `try` block; the first time you store it in a variable that you never use, and the second time you print the value but throw it away. Are you certain you want to be doing both things?

Comment: No I probably wont and alot of this code is pure crap to be honest and could be deleted but I dont really care about that, I know this code isnt pretty its just makedue to get things running so I can submit my project to my university but I just want to know if someone can explain the fact that changing a catch can prevent a crash.

Comment: That sounds rough, I know alot of code is just "filler" code when I was trying to get things working that haven been deleted. I wont try to optimize this in any way, any "filler" code left will be just that, only left in the code because it doesnt hurt my intent which is getting it to work. But the fact that changin a catch from IOException to Exception not only saves my app from crashing but also lets it run as intended

Comment: The only way your code will ever work is if you program with complete _intention_. Be sure you know why every single line of code is in your program. You are throwing away at least two lines of input from the server. If you do not know why, you code can never be called **correct** or **working**. You might not have found the bug yet but the only way code can be called correct is if it complies with your expectations.

Comment: The thing is I have the server running on my netbook side by side with my client, I can see everything I write to the server and I know what the server should and do respond and my client does print it all as is specified by the server. I cant explain it better then that everything is working just the way it should even though the code might say otherwise somehow. Im not trying to be a jackass here just want to know why this is because logically shouldnt be right?

Comment: its not throwing away two lines. I know the server, I know its commands and responses and ive got it running side by side so I see when I write to it and what it responds and sure enough I get that exact response when its supposed to come in. If im sounding like jerk I apologize but the fact is the code shouldnt work but it somehow does which is more annoying than it not working and leaving me to look for errors. Its like im now catching the error but it just keeps on running and working anyway despite the error.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I better understand you now. :)

Comment: @sek. Not trying to be a dick, but but your statement "Its like im now catching the error but it just keeps on running and working anyway despite the error." is the whole problem. You simply do not understand exception handling, to be frank. When you catch an exception, YOU are responsible for handling it correctly and the OS will no longer handle it for you. The fact that you are ignoring the exception is why you no longer crash. The fact that you are getting an exception means that no, your app is not doing exactly what you intend.